# Can I export a list of user and their roles from ArcGIS Server 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, user-account

I need to export a list of all users and roles in ArcGIS Server 10.0. Does anyone know if there is a method to do this?

Comment: It might be hard to do as scripting was poor in 10. Look here http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISSERVER/10.0/HELP/ARCGIS_SERVER_DOTNET_HELP/index.html#/Overview_of_setting_up_users_and_roles/0093000000pw000000/ - maybe you could parse some config files trying to get users from there.